# Extract data from same title but different xml response

Tags: jmeter

I trying to extract data from xml response using RegEx. But problem is different xml response but same tag. How do i extract both of them.

[This is first xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1tJW.jpg)

[This is second xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBDOp.jpg)

As u see there are same tag named "AcctId" but contain different data.

Comment: Hi.  please edit your question and show the xml and how you are trying to extract it.  take a minute to read [ask].  thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. In the first case the value you're looking for is under `CAAcctId` tag
2. In the second case the value you're looking for is under `AcctId` tag

just amend your regex to check the previous line and it should start working as you expect.

Also given you're getting XML it might make more sense to go for [XPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0/) which allows executing arbitrary [XPath queries](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) to fetch data from XML/XHTML responses, it will be more readable, robust and reliable than trying to parse XML with regular expressions which are sensitive to markup change

Comment: thank u for ur answer ill try it as u say and let u know back.

Comment: How i check previous line ```CAAcctId``` is has no ending tag.